# i don't get it. why i just cant use int('something) in this code? why i need to make another variable like value = float('something)?

Tags: python

1st one is ok.
but in second one it showed:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'done'

```
count = 0
total = 0
while True :
    inp =input('enter number : ')
    if inp == 'done': break
    value = float(inp)
    count = count + 1
    total = total + value
print(count)
print(total)
print(total/count)
```

2nd :

```
count = 0
total = 0
while True :
    inp =int(input('enter number : '))
    if inp == 'done': break
    count = count + 1
    total = total + inp
print(count)
print(total)
print(total/count)
```

Comment: Do `value = int(imp)` like with your float example. You can’t turn `'done'` into a float.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Think carefully about the intended logic of your code. In your own words, what does `int` do? What do you expect to be the result of `int('done')`? Why? Therefore, what happens when the user types that?

Answer (score 1):

Right here

```
inp =int(input('enter number : '))
```

You are casting your input to int. So when you type `'done'` to console, you get error, because it's not a valid integer

Answer (score 0):

`int('done')` isn't a integer. So the `int()` function returns an exception.

Answer (score 0):

inp is an integer. Therefore, you can't ask whether it's equal to a string('done'), because you're comparing different things.